# Do I need a transit visa for Morocco (Casablanca) and Guinea-Bissau for a short layover?

Tags: visas, transit, transit-visas, morocco, guinea-bissau

I'm travelling to Gambia and I have two layover in Morocco and Guinea Bissau for 1 hour each place. Do I need a transit visa? I have a Travel Document from Denmark (it's a blue passport) and I'm not a citizen of Denmark yet. I'm a citizen of Afghanistan, but have lived in Denmark for 22 years (if that matters).

Comment: Does the travel document state that you're Afghan? If not, do you also have an Afghan passport?

Comment: Yes it says so and no I don't have an Afghan passport :-)

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: does the *fremmedpas* state your NATIONALITY as Afghan, or only place of birth? My answer applies if your NATIONALITY is stated as Afghan

Comment: Yes, I think it does - I can check when I get home, but I'm almost certain that it does

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airlines:

For [Morocco](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=MA&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=TW&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL):

> Transit without visa: Holders of confirmed onward tickets for a max. transit
>     time of 24 hours at Casablanca (CMN).

For [Guinea-Bissau](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?FullText=1&COUNTRY=GW&SECTION=VI&SUBSECTION=TW&user=PEARL&subuser=PEARL):

> Transit without visa: Holders of confirmed onward tickets in transit

So no, you do **not** need visas.

P.S. Get Danish citizenship as soon as possible - it will be well worth it.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! And I'm in the process of getting the citizenship :-))